# Visual Studio unit test refuses to run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I am starting to test a school project using the Visual Studio and the built in unit tester. The project is a class library written in C#. All of my tests up to this point have worked. However, I still have 1 test that will not run. It's not passing or failing, it simply doesn't run. There are no error messages given and I can not get it to run or debug or anything. Here is the test I am attempting:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void PublicDecimalEqualityTest2()
    {
        Formula form1 = new Formula("2.3232000+3.00");
        Formula form2 = new Formula("2.3232+3.0000");
        Assert.IsTrue(form1==form2);
    }
```

The "==" operator for my class is defined correctly. Strangely enough this test runs and passes:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void PublicDecimalEqualityTest()
    {
        Formula form1 = new Formula("2.3232000+3.00");
        Formula form2 = new Formula("2.3232+3.0000");
        Assert.IsTrue(form1.Equals(form2));
    }
```

Any idea why the first test posted won't run?

Edit: Here is the code for the `==` operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(Formula f1, Formula f2) {
    if (f1==null && f2==null)
    { return true; }
    if (f1==null || f2==null)
    {return false;}
    if (f1.GetFormulaBasic()==f2.GetFormulaBasic())
    { return true; }
    else
    { return false;}
}
```

`GetFormulaBasic()` simply returns a private string from the class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show us the == operator?

Comment: I'm going to guess your code is causing a StackOverflow exception in the `==` operator which is causing the runner to crash without a result.

Comment: Have you tried debugging (stepping through) the test method?

Comment: I don't think it's a StackOverflow exception. My "==" only tests for null objects and string equivalency between two objects. If it is possible to get a StackOverflow exception from that, would you mind explaining how that would be possible?

Comment: No, my guess is exactly right. `f1 == null` is going to call the `==` operator. The one you are implementing. Hence, a stack overflow. Use `Object.ReferenceEquals` to test for nulls inside an operator.

Comment: @David The test will not run in debugging mode. It simply refuses to run. When I click "Run All", 9 tests complete with 1 test in the "Not Run Tests" section. Even trying to manually run the test on its own regularly, or in debug, does nothing.

Comment: @mikez Oh my goodness! That makes complete sense! Just another dumb error on my part. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mikez Just implement the Object.ReferenceEquals method. Worked perfectly and my test now runs and passes. Thank you again for your  help.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm surprised there's not a way to see these "runner-level" errors. There used to be in the old test results view, but I'm not sure where it is in the new Test Window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess was correct. You are calling the operator `==` inside your implementation when you are checking for null. Replace `==` with `Object.ReferenceEquals` to test for null inside the operator. Here it is, simplified a little:

```
public static bool operator ==(Formula f1, Formula f2)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2))
    { 
        return true; 
    }
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(f2, null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return f1.GetFormulaBasic() == f2.GetFormulaBasic();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you for your help. I spaced out and didn't realize that my operator was recursively calling itself.